# how to use %20 as data in URL

Tags: perl, url

My URL contains data to be updated 
data format is "Testing%20(1.2.5)"
it is getting updated as "Testing (1.2.5)", %20 is not coming so please suggest me what to use in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?foo=Testing%20(1.2.5)` means value `Testing (1.2.5)` was provided for `foo`.

If the sender wanted to submit `Testing%20(1.2.5)`, they should have used `?foo=Testing%2520(1.2.5)`.

```
$ perl -MURI -E'say for URI->new("?foo=Testing%20(1.2.5)")->query_form();'
foo
Testing (1.2.5)

$ perl -MURI -E'say for URI->new("?foo=Testing%2520(1.2.5)")->query_form();'
foo
Testing%20(1.2.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

`%` indicates the start of an encoded character in a URL.

If you want a `%` as data then you must use the encoded version of it: `%25`